# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ converges, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Question: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ converges, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists.

Solution: Let $(a_m)_{m\ge 1}$ be the series defined by the partial sum $$a_m=\sum_{n=1}^m (x_{n+1}-x_n), \forall m\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Note that by our definition, it follows that $$a_m=x_{m+1}-x_1, \forall m\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Now since it is given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ converges, implies that the series $(a_m)_{m\ge 1}$ is absolutely convergent, which in turn implies that $(a_m)_{m\ge 1}$ is convergent. From here we can conclude that the sequence $(x_{m+1}-x_1)_{m\ge 1}$ converges, which implies that the sequence $(x_{m+1})_{m\ge 1}$ converges, that is, the sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge 1}$ converges. Hence we are done.

Is this solution correct and rigorous enough and is there any other way to solve this problem (possibly without using absolute convergence)?

Comment: I guess I have never mentioned that in the solution, rather I have mentioned that since $\sum (x_{n+1}-x_n)$ converges, implies that $(x_{m+1}-x_1)_{m\ge 1}$ converges.

Comment: Ok, that was my mistake. What you have written makes sense then.

Comment: not a proof but a potentially fruitful thought: since $\sum_{n\ge1}|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ converges, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{n+1}-x_n|=0$. That's all I can think of for now

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct, the most important step is to derive convergence from absolute convergence，I think this is the most concise solution. For another way, you can prove that $x_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence by conditions, and then get the conclusion. But I think there is no essential difference between the two solutions.